# Automator/AppleScript: move folders to a location based on their name

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, script

I'm very new to scripting and Automator but I am trying to figure out a way to have folders automatically moved to a desired location based on the beginning and ending of their names. for example:

```
If folder name starts with "A" and ends with "45" move to Documents/Archive/A/45
```

or

```
if folder name starts with "J" and ends with "29" move to Documents/Archive/J/29
```

Edit:

1. Real world folder name would be: A761245 or J647929
2. Yes the destination folders already exist
3. No, the source folder and destination folder are in different locations.
4. I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6⁩

Is there a way to do this with automator or scripting? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Pete, what have you achieved so far?

Comment: 1. Please edit your post adding in some _real-world full names_ of the _folders_ to be moved. 2. Do the _destination folders_ for the _move_ operation already exist? 3. Are the _source folders_ and _destination folders_ all within the same _folder?_ 4. What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @grg The only thing I've been able to achieve so far is a headache. I've tooled around with automator and tried to find tutorials but have had no luck. I'm really out of my element here and any guidance or advise is appreciated.

Comment: @user3439894 I edited my post. Any other questions please let me know.

Comment: Pete, did the answer I provided help you to resolve your issue?

Comment: Pete, did the answer I provided help you to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I opened **Terminal**, which by default opens to ones *home directory*, and ran the following *command*:

```
mkdir -p  ./Documents/Archive/A/45 ./Documents/Archive/J/29 A761245 J647929
```

This created two new *directories*, `A761245` and `J647929`, in the *root* of my *home directory* and the *hierarchal directory structure* within my `Documents` *directory* to receive them when moved.

I then use the following *compound command* to move any *directory* whose *name* started with an *upper case alpha character* followed by *six numeric characters*:

```
for d in *; do [[ -d $d ]] || continue; if [[ $d =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then mv -n -v "$d" "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/"; fi; done
```

The result of this *compound command* was:

```
A761245 -> ./Documents/Archive/A/45/A761245
J647929 -> ./Documents/Archive/J/29/J647929
$
```

This *compound command* could be used in a `bash` *script*, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    [[ -d $d ]] || continue
    if [[ $d =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then
        mv -n -v "$d" "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/"
    fi
done
```

This basically works by testing the *name* of any *directory* passed to conform to an *upper case alpha character* followed by *six numeric characters*  using *capture groups* and `BASH_REMATCH` to build the appropriate destination *pathname* for the `mv` *command*.

I know you said the *destination directories* already exist and the example `bash` *code* above takes that for granted without any additional *error handling*.  With that said though, you could add a line of *code* that would create the necessary *hierarchal directory structure* first, as in the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    [[ -d $d ]] || continue
    if [[ $d =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then
        mkdir -p "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        mv -n -v "$d" "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/"
    fi
done
```

The one-liner *compound command* would be:

```
for d in *; do [[ -d $d ]] || continue; if [[ $d =~ ^([A-Z])([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then mkdir -p "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"; mv -n -v "$d" "./Documents/Archive/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/"; fi; done
```

**I'd use this version of the *compound command* and or `bash` *script*.**

---

**Note:** Using the `-p` *option* with the `mkdir` *command* will create the *hierarchal directory structure* as needed without erring out if it already exists. This would be that way I'd go just to make sure you do not try moving a *source directory* to a nonexistent *destination directory*.